# Таблица на языке C

Tags: c

Можно ли реализовать такую таблицу на языке С?

[image: табличка]

Первая строчка задается автоматически, № тоже, а далее необходимо, чтобы пользователь вводил необходимую информацию. Я пробовал делать с табуляцией \t но все тщетно.

Вот собственно сам кусок кода:

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct library
{
    char LastNAME[100];
    char FirstNAME[100];
    char MiddleNAME[100];
    int BirthDate, BirthMonth, BirthYear;
    char Address[100];
    int PhoneNumberMOBILE;
    int PhoneNumberWORK;

}notebook[10];


void DataInitialization()  //Инициализация данных
{
    FILE* F;
    char fname[100];
    int NumberOfEntries=0;
    printf("Укажите имя файла, в котором будет хранится база данных (как на примере: text.txt)\n-> ");
    scanf_s("%s", fname, sizeof(fname));
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    if ((F = fopen(fname, "w+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Невозможно открыть для чтения файл \n");
        return;
    };
    printf("Сколько записей вы хотите сделать?\n -> ");
    scanf_s("%d", &NumberOfEntries);                                                        //ЗАМЕНИТЬ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ
    printf("№ |  Фамилия  |  Имя  |  Отчество  |  Дата Рождения  |  Адрес  |  моб.телефон  |  раб.телефон  |\n");
    
    /*while (1)
    {*/
        for (int i = 1; i <= NumberOfEntries; i++)
        {
            /*if (_getch() == 27) break;*/
            printf("%2.d|", i);
        
        }
    /*}*/
    

}

void ViewData() //Просмотр существующей базы данных 
{

}

void DataEdit() //Редактирование базы данных
{

}

void AddData() //Дополнение базы данных новыми записями 
{

}

void DeleteData() //Удаление данных
{

}

void SearchData() //Поиск в базе данных
{

}

void SortData() //Сортировка данных по заданному полю
{

}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    
    int menu=1;
    while (menu != 0)
    {
        printf("Выберите, что вам нужно сделать\n"
               "0 -> Выход из программы\n"
               "1 -> Создание новой базы данных\n"
               "2 -> Просмотр существующей базы данных\n"
               "3 -> Редактирование базы данных\n"
               "4 -> Дополнение базы данных новыми записями\n"
               "5 -> Удаление записей из базы данных\n"
               "6 -> Поиск в базе данных\n"
               "7 -> Сортировка данных по заданному полю\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &menu);

        if (menu > 7)
            printf("Пж выберите цифру из предложенного списка:\n\n");

        switch (menu)
        {
        case 1:
            DataInitialization();//Инициализация данных
            break;
        case 2:
            ViewData(); //Просмотр существующей базы данных 
            break;
        case 3:
            DataEdit(); //Редактирование базы данных
            break;
        case 4:
            AddData(); //Дополнение базы данных новыми записями 
            break;
        case 5:
            DeleteData(); //Удаление данных
            break;
        case 6:
            SearchData(); //Поиск в базе данных
            break;
        case 7:
            SortData(); //Сортировка данных по заданному полю
            break;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Надо напечатать данные в таком виде? Почему через `\t` не получается? Какие ошибки/вывод получаете? Приведите код, который касается отображения

Comment: @dIm0n Да, именно в таком виде. Вывод получается не такой как я хочу, когда вписываю фамилию, она сразу перескакивает на следующую строчку.

Comment: Подозреваю, для сложных интерфейсов лучше взять ncurses или что-то вроде того

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> когда вписываю фамилию, она сразу перескакивает на следующую строчку.

Разумеется, именно так и должно быть. Дело в том, что собственно передача данных с клавиатуры в Вашу программу выполняется драйвером ОС только **после** того, как Вы нажали Enter. И то - не сразу. Сначала драйвер пытается откорректировать то, что Вы (возможно) правили клавишей "Забой" или как-то ещё. И только потом передаёт **всю** строку в программу.

Поэтому, при вводе сложных данных (как у Вас) есть только два варианта:

1. Вводить сразу всю строку и уже внутри программы самостоятельно разбирать её на элементы и выполнять присваивания элементам данных;
2. Вводить данные поэлементно, а красивую табличку печатать по окончанию ввода.

@andreymal рекомнендует Вам использовать ncurses. Да, для такой задачи - подходящий инструмент. Но, боюсь, что для начинающего это будет тяжело...

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: можно. С помощью модификаторов форматированной строки ([Подробнее](https://cpp.com.ru/shildt_spr_po_c/08/0804.html)) можно организовать ширину полей. К [примеру](https://ideone.com/Vm9Hcv):

```
printf("№ |  Фамилия  |  Имя  |  Отчество  |  Дата Рождения  |  Адрес  |  моб.телефон  |  раб.телефон  |\n");
printf("%-2d| %-9s | %-5s | %-10s |   %02d.%02d.%04d    | %-7s |  %-11d  |  %-11d  |\n", 5, "Ivanov", "Ivan", "Ivanovich", 18, 8, 2020, "Moscow", 100 , 5555);
```

Цифры перед спецификаторами указывают на ширину отведённого под строку поля, знак `-` производит выравнивание по левому краю.